# wrapping mongo update in function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Whats the proper way to wrap a mongo query/insert in a function to make it reusable? I have an update operation that may take place in various places and want to only write it once and reuse it. I'm using MongoJS to interface w/ the MongoDb API.

When I take something like the following:

```
 mongo.myt.update(
        {'_id': req._id},
        {
            $addToSet: {
                "aggregate.clientIds": req.myt.clientIds
            },
            $inc: {"aggregate.seenCount": 1},
            $set: {
                "headers": req.myt.headers,
                "ip": req.myt.ip
            },
            $setOnInsert: {
                '_id': req.myt._id,
                'derived': req.myt.derived
            }
        },
        {upsert: true},
        function (err, savedId) {
            if (err || !savedId) console.log("failed to save :" + req.myt + " because of " + err);
            else console.log("successfully saved :" + req.myt);
        });
```

And wrap it with a simple function like:

```
function mongoInsert(req) {
   //same query as above
}
```

Then call it using:

```
 mongoInsert(req);
```

I don't see any impact to speed when profiling. Should I be adding a callback to the wrapper function, is that needed? I was expecting it would have some performance impact and need to be done differently.

So a few questions.

1. Does the approach above calling mongoInsert() get called synchronously and block until the async mongo update is done?
2. If it does become sync, I would expect a performance impact which I didnt see. So is the approach I took ok to use?
3. And if not what would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Your approach is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongoInsert()` is still asynchronous because it's calling an asynchronous function (`mongo.myt.update()`). Even if you don't add a callback function, it won't magically become synchronous.

The way you wrote it now is *"fire-and-forget"*: somewhere in your code you call `mongoInsert()`, your code will continue to run while the update is taking place, and since you don't pass a callback the calling code cannot get informed about the result of the update (right now, you're just logging the result to console).

It's a design decision whether or not this is acceptable.

You could make the callback optional for situations where you do want to get informed about the update result:

```
function mongoInsert(req, callback) {
  callback = callback || function() {}; // dummy callback when none is provided
  mongo.myt.update(..., function(err, savedId) {
    ...log status here...
    callback(err, savedId);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!